# php date() not receiving year, month, day: NSDate to php

Tags: php, ios, date, nsdate

I have a php web service and am sending an NSDate from an iOS app to the web service.  This is my php for receiving the date:

```
echo 'formatted T/S '.$u_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['timestamp'])));
```

This is the date that I am sending with my url:

```
timestamp=2015-09-03%2013:52:09%20+0000
```

I am receiving it fine, but my output is this:

```
1970-01-01 00:33:35
```

Does someone know what is wrong with my php that I am not receiving the NSDate correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` function takes a *Unix* timestamp as the second parameter (i.e. the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`)

Try this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['timestamp']))));
```

Comment: Great, that works perfect, except my year equals 0000.  example: (0000-09-03 13:52:09)  What can I do to get correct year?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `+0000` is confusing `strtotime`

Comment: so I should send the 'timestamp' as a string without the milliseconds and that would work.. I took the '%20+0000' off the end of my answer and it updated my database with the correct timestamp.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah, try that. `strtotime` is relatively resilient, and will accept most common formats (as well as strings like `today`, or `yesterday`, or `+3 months`). My own local tests don'e seem to be confused by the milliseconds, but that doesn't mean that the exact format that your copy is receiving isn't confusing it.

Comment: Works like a charm, sending an NSString same format as NSDate without milliseconds and no problems.